# Is there a way to figure out which View caused an Exception (android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep developing my very first android app. It has several EditText views, which the user is supposed to fill in in order to get a result. If no data is entered, then when I parse data from an empty EditText into an int for subsequent calculation, I get the NumberFormatException. What I want to do is if the user forgot to enter data in some EditText, I need to get the ID of that view and change it's hint color into red. So is there a way for an exception handler to grab the ID of the view, which has caused the exception?

Comment: Please include some code to show how you handle your EditText views and the data parsing

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be need a TextInputEditText? or you just need to judge whether the content of EditText is empty. If it is empty, set up an error prompt?

Comment: There are several EditText fields, so I want to write a method, which would parse an int from all of those fileds and pass them on for subsequent calculation. If the user has forgotten to fill in some field, I want to mark it with a different color. So I guess it would be cool if, when NumberFormatException happens, which exactly view caused it. So, I am wondering if it is possible to get the ID of the view that caused an exception? I am sorry if this question is silly, I am very new to programming in general.

Comment: After searching the website, I found that it can be implemented through handler, but I can't provide more specific content. I can give you a few links, maybe these links will help you: https://blog.csdn.net/zhangzheng0602/article/details/69383926, https://blog.csdn.net/chenlove1/article/details/71423032. These websites are all in Chinese. I'm not sure if you can visit them. In addition, I am a Chinese, my English is not good, so I don't know if I can express my meaning clearly.

Comment: Thank you pnkj! I will use a translator and look through. Thanks again!